# functionality regarding updating row data not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Recently some days before i have started asp.net so i am facing some difficulties so now i faced first problem that i am not able to configure to it.My problem is that i have a webform in which i have two fields Name and desciption below that one button and below grid view .

i have applied required field validation on field so problem is when i click data adding in database and showing in grid view edit and delete functionality of grid view but when i am click on update it's not doing update and due to required field validtors applied on fields so
that's my problem i am also attaching my code as well as code may be u can grab.

aspx Code:-

```
<div id="Organization-Form" class="CssForm">
            <p>Create New Project</p>
            <div id="fields">
                <table width="100%" title="New Project" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="*Name:" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Input_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Please Enter Name" 
                                   TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="txt-input-class" Height="20px" 
                                   Width="191px" ToolTip="Please Enter Name"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Name_Required" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="Txt_Input_Name" 
                                                    ErrorMessage="Name is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="Name is required." Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"
                                                    >* Name is required.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="*Description:" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox placeholder="Please Enter Description" CssClass="txt-input-class" ID="Txt_Input_Description" runat="server"
                                TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" 
                                   Width="191px" ToolTip="Please Enter Description" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Description_Required" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="Txt_Input_Description" 
                                                    ErrorMessage="Description is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="Description is required." Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"
                                                    >* Description is required.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <div id="btn-div" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                                  <asp:Button CssClass="btn" ID="submit_button" Text="Create Project" runat="server" OnClick="submit_button_Click" />
                            </div>
                         </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="Grid" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
                        BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="5" 
                        CellSpacing="5" ForeColor="Black" Width="931px" 
                        PageSize="4">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" Visible="false"
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
            SortExpression="Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" 
            HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsActive" 
            HeaderText="Is Active" SortExpression="IsActive" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateDate" 
            HeaderText="Create Date" SortExpression="CreateDate" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifyDate" 
            HeaderText="Modify Date" SortExpression="ModifyDate" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" 
            HeaderText="Created By" SortExpression="CreatedBy" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ connectionString%>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Projects] WHERE [Id] = @Id" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalSqlServer.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name], [Description], [IsActive], [CreateDate], [ModifyDate], [CreatedBy] FROM [Projects]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Projects] SET [Name] = @Name, [Description] = @Description, [IsActive] = @IsActive, [CreateDate] = @CreateDate, [ModifyDate] = @ModifyDate, [CreatedBy] = @CreatedBy WHERE [Id] = @Id">
                        <DeleteParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
                        </DeleteParameters>
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="IsActive" Type="Boolean" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CreateDate" Type="DateTime" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ModifyDate" Type="DateTime" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CreatedBy" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
                        </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </tr>                  
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

aspx.cs Code:-

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void clear()
    {
        Txt_Input_Name.Text = "";
        Txt_Input_Description.Text = "";

    }


    protected void submit_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "insert fields working well";
        DbObj.ExecuteStringQuery(sqlQuery);
        clear();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and here is image screen shot that u can on update click its not updating instead showing required field validation and when i add values in above text boxes then update in gridview its working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWkGG.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a validation group to your add fields and buttons, that way when you do an update from the `GridView` it will not trigger validation.

As an example for your name validator add this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Name_Required" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="Txt_Input_Name" 
                                                    ErrorMessage="Name is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="Name is required." Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" validationgroup="Add"
                                                    >* Name is required.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Add this to your description:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Description_Required" runat="server" 
                                                    ControlToValidate="Txt_Input_Description" 
                                                    ErrorMessage="Description is required." 
                                                    ToolTip="Description is required." Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" validationgroup="Add" 
                                                    >* Description is required.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

And finally your add button:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn" ID="submit_button" Text="Create Project" runat="server" OnClick="submit_button_Click" validationgroup="Add" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: waow Thanx alot bro and give me link also for reading now i understand how can we create prevent this type of things regarding validation hmmm. @hutchonoid